Chainlink VRF pending forever
My requests to the Chainlink VRF remain pending indefinitely. The same contract works correctly on the BSC Testnet, but when I switch to the Mainnet, it doesn't work. I have changed the Gas Lane and the callbackGasLimit multiple times, but nothing works. My latest attempt used a Gas Lane of 200 Gwei and a callbackGasLimit of 100,000. I'm trying with 3 confirmations and only 1 word. It seems like the cost goes up to 2 LINK, and I can't understand how generating a random number can be this expensive. What could I be doing wrong?
OBS: I currently have 1 LINK in my subscription funding, and I cannot accept that generating a random number costs more than this amount.

I added 1.5 more Link to the subscription fund to make it higher than the Max Cost. It worked twice, but now, even though the subscription fund is greater than the Max Cost, it's still pending.

I set the LINK value in the VRF significantly higher than the MaxCost, and now it works perfectly.
